# How to execute some commands while background task of bash script is about to be killed

Tags: 12.04, bash, gnome-terminal

In case i run a script in terminal and it contains a background job , in case the user close the terminal as i guess the script with his all back ground tasks will be dead , i want something like an event when the job is about to be killed or terminated , to excecute some block of code 
for instance :

```
while sleep 3h
do
backGround job commands 
done
those above is the back ground job
```

i want when i already pressed exit on the terminal who run the script in background and when this job is about to exist and killed to do some other commands before get terminated the whole script something like EVENTS in C# for example when something happen a block of code get executed 
i hope i explained myself abundantly clear this time

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You need `screen` i guess. screen will keep the process in the background and it will not be terminat even if the terminal is closed by the user.

Comment: THanks sir , but this is not what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script will append Caught to the Test.Out file, whenever it receives SIGINT, SIGTERM, SIGHUP

```
#!/bin/bash

trap "echo 'Caught' >> Test.Out" SIGINT SIGTERM SIGHUP
while :
do
   sleep 1000
done
```

I like **SIGHUP** the most. It will be sent to the shell script whenever the terminal is closed.

But we cannot escape the KILL signal. :( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGKILL#SIGKILL

**EDIT:** More Info on SIGHUP : http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html#index-hangup-signal-2859

**EDIT:** Video with Test.Out file generation http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qP0zClZZZHc

Comment: i am reading to understan what SIGHUP means thanks for answer

Comment: in case it will for sure i will accept it  :)

Comment: look sir , it works but in case i open using Ctrl+T to open terminal on my own then i drag and drop the file of the bashscript to run it by pressing Enter the file is created on pressing close by mouse but in case i double click on the file of the bashscript it open terminal on its own when i press to close it , it creates nothing .. so any further explanation ? :)

Comment: Are you sure? It creates the file for me.

Comment: yes i tried it by myself it happens as i say above exactly

Comment: I have included a link to the Youtube video, in the answer, which shows how it works for me.

Comment: yes that is the case  i mean sir and it doesnt work with me and in terminal i get this message `trap: SIGINT: bad trap`

Comment: Do you use ksh shell?

Comment: no i dont use it

Answer (score 1):

In case you wan't to execute some code before being executed you could use `trap`:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 trap "echo Exiting" SIGINT SIGTERM
 read
```

More info [here](http://linux.die.net/Bash-Beginners-Guide/sect_12_02.html).

Comment: i am reading to understan what SIGINT means thanks for answer

Answer (score 1):

You might want the [`at` command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/at.1.html):

```
at 3 hours <<END
backGround job commands 
END
```

Comment: this will end the background ask after those 3h , right ?

Comment: No, it will launch the task 3 hours from now, I thought that's what you wanted.

Comment: hank u it is nice piece of information really but it is not what i want :)